# VBA code to run query in Teradata and paste results in Excel

Tags: vba, teradata

I cannot figure out why this VBA is not working to run a query in Teradata and paste the results in an excel spreadsheet

this is the error I am getting: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQl Server does not exist or access denied."

I don't believe it is because my access is denied because when I add my username and password to the code it still doesn't work.

CODE:

```
Sub sql_query()

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlQry As String, sConnect As String

sqlQry = "SEL * FROM entpr_tx_actuarial.mrm sample 10;"

sConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=[Teradata-DATA.*****.com]; Database=[TERADATA_PRD];Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Conn.Open sConnect

Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset

    recset.Open sqlQry, Conn
    Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset recset
    recset.Close

Conn.Close

Set recset = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at your connection string.  Here's a hint:  `Driver={SQL Server};`

Comment: @Andrew what am I supposed to put in for the driver? sorry I am very new to this :)

Comment: I know nothing about VBA, but you need to specify the Teradata driver, not SQL Server.  Maybe try `Driver={Teradata}`

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Does anyone else know what I need to put in for Driver and where I can find it (if this is actually the issue)?

Comment: Do you have a Teradata client driver installed? What type and what is its actual name? For example, is it `Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20`? If so, you should be able to use that name inside the { }. (Older versions of the driver were in fact named just `Teradata` but newer ones are not.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know what driver you have installed then you need to supply the information for that driver.  In this case it should not be SQL Server.  If you don't know what is installed or how to use it, then it can be a little hard to figure out.  So here is a trick I use to build my connection strings.

Use notepad or some other text editor to create an empty file.  Name it so that the file extention is .udl.  Make sure .udl is the extension and not actually part of the file name.  If file extensions are hidden by default, you might have to change your folder options to show file extensions in order to get this to work.

After creating the file, double click on it. It will open a connection wizard.  On the Provider tab look for one that seems like it will work...probably an ODBC or Teradata provider.  If there doesn't seem to be anything reasonable then you may need to install a driver.

Go to the connection tab and supply the info you want to use to connect.  Hit the "Test Connection" button to see if it works.

If it worked, click on ok.  Now open the udl file with notepad.  It will display the actual values used for the connection string.  You should be able to just copy and paste the values into your VBA connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is still looking at this for an answer I use this to build my connection string in Excel Office 365:

```
strDriver = "{Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20}"
strConn = "yourserveraddress"
strDB = "yourdatabasename"
strUID = "youruserid"
strPW = "yourpassword"

strConnection = "ODBC" & _
        ";DRIVER=" & strDriver & _
        ";DBCNAME=" & strConn & _
        ";DEFAULTDATABASE=" & strDB & _
        ";DESCRIPTION=Intelliflex;EN"), Array("ABLEPWD=1;ENABLEWALLET=0;MECHANISMNAME=LDAP" & _
        ";PWD=" & strPW & _
        ";UID=" & strUID & _
        ";USEINTEGRATEDSECURITY=0;"
```